# c# math cos different values from calculator

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to do a precision type of program where i encountered values there were wrong and have been able to pinpoint the problem area. The **Math.cos** values differ from the calculator values and how can i correct this for instance

```
Math.Cos(28.545742)
```

gives the value **-0.963394351754924** but on all other calculators it gives me a correct value of **0.8784358937** which is perfect since it completes the expected program output. How can I get Math.Cos to give me the answers I want? and this is my first time messing with C# math functions.

Comment: I would guess that `C#` is working in radians, but "all other calculators" are working in degrees.

Comment: You need to specify the angle in radians, not degrees.

Comment: The other comments are correct... https://www.google.com/#q=cosine+28.545742 also shows the -0.96.. answer, using radians.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Math.Cos()` is using radians while your calculator is using degrees. A simple way to convert from degrees to radians is degrees*(pi/180).

In code:

```
Math.Cos(28.545742*(Math.PI/180))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the angle in radians, not degrees.

There are `2*pi` radians in a circle, and 360 degrees. So to convert degrees to radians, divide by 360 and multiply by `2*pi` (simplified: multiply by `pi/180`):

```
Math.Cos(28.545742 * Math.PI / 180f)
```

Will give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Cos` function takes values in radians.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the detailed explanation on MSDN site about the function.

Comment: Every language that I know of - FORTRAN, C, C++, Java, C#, Python, Javascript - all expect angles in radians.